# htaccess PHP MVC Redirect to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my htacess file.

I have a php mvc system set up with the root looking like 
public [folder]
application [folder]
htaccess

The first htaccess reads

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]

RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This is to remove public from the url i assume ?

The second htaccess file i have is in the public directory with the index.php file which starts the php app

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/public) /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This has been written to force the url to go to https rather than http, The problem im having is if the url is typed into the url bar as http://example.com and the rewrite happens it will take me to https://example.com/public, I am trying to remove the public directory from the url if this happens, Any help would be much apreciated.

Cheers
Ryan

Comment: Thankyou so much, I didn't even think about having the document root set as public.
Write this as an answer and ill accept it, Ive been pretty stupid (First MVC app)

Comment: Added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrites doesn't remove parts or change the URL in the users browser.

The first htaccess simply makes all requests to `/` load files from the `/public`-folder internally, without the user noticing.

If you don't want `/public` to be available, you should change the document root to point to the public folder instead of the folder above.

Comment: Cheers Mate :).